# IDW interpolation in ModelBuilder by column in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, interpolation, inverse-distance-weighted

I want to interpolate using the IDW method in ArcMap. I have to interpolate the values of several months for several years. I have the data in a shapefile in which each column has the values for each month (see image below). I want to do it in ModelBuilder as I have to perform an important number of interpolations.

How can I indicate in ModelBuilder to loop over each column and export the interpolated raster with the name of the column?

[image]

Comment: What does your model so far look like?

Answer (score 1):

I know you have tagged your question as ArcMap but this can be done easily in ArcGIS Pro as that provides a ModelBuilder [iterator that loops over fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-fields.htm) in a dataset. The model is simply:

[image: Model]

No such iterator exists in ArcMap so you would have to provide\build a list of fields that could drive the model. I would suggest in ArcMap that this is probably best done as a simple script as you have better control over looping. The arcpy function [ListFields](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm) would be the scripting equivalent to the ArcGIS Pro iterator.